# display if parent has_term but not child has_term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

International the parent term, Canada is the child term. I'd like for text to display if in the parent category except for one of the child categories (both are custom taxonomies.) This has not worked. Is there another way to write this?

```
if(has_term('International') && !has_term ('Canada', 'International')) { echo 'Text to display.'; }
```

Comment: qual o nome do seu termo registrado? colocar o código que deve ser usado para registrador ou termo